# How can I determine which platform is running?

Tags: google-chrome-app

How can I determine which device is running?

My app runs well on Windows, Linux and OSX. but doesn't on CrOS(Chromebook).

So I'd like to sperate code like a..

```
> if (chrome.systemInfo.platform == CrOS) {
>     // code only for CrOs }
```

Is there anyway to do this way? anyway to get the information of platform?

Comment: OS detection is discouraged, feature detection preferred. What if your app can run on a Chromebook you don't have, or one in the future you don't know about yet? Can you describe on apps-dev@chromium.org or crbug.com/new why it doesn't run on CrOS so we can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChromeOS has the [`navigator.userAgent` of "CrOS"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/NJRJvvXGr58). So the base on the fact, you could have a conditional statement like...:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('CrOS') != -1) {
    console.log('ChromeOS');
} else {
    console.log('Other platform');
}
```